# select row from table view and get data into variable then display it in QRcode image

Tags: select, observable, tableview, addeventlistener, qr-code

get data from table view and put it into variable a,  [image] then display a in qrcode image [image]

[image]
what's your suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
  //ObservableList<Utilisateur> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();        
                 TABLEUSER.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     if (newValue != null) {
                try {
                
            // a=null;
           a  = (newValue.getId_user()  + " | "+ newValue.getNom()+ " | " + newValue.getPrenom());
                
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                 //String details = txt_nom.getText()+txt_adresse.getText();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(a).to(ImageType.PNG ).stream() ;
                File f = new File("C:\\Users\\ACHRAF\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\singleton_JDBC\\src\\QRcode\\Mychannel.png") ;
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f,false);
                    fos.write (out.toByteArray()) ;
                     fos.flush();                   
                     fos.close();                   
                     refresh_table();
//                       list.clear();
                         System.out.println(newValue.getId_user() +    " | "+ newValue.getNom() + " | " +     newValue.getPrenom());
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(ADMINController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(ADMINController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
      }
```